# Original paper on Lorentz representation theory

Tags: special-relativity, particle-physics, representation-theory, specific-reference

Which was the original paper on the representations of the Lorentz group? Is there even one paper on this, or was this knowledge gained iteratively in a series of papers?

Comment: [E. Wigner Annals of Mathematics Second Series, Vol. 40, No. 1 (Jan., 1939), pp. 149-204](http://www.jstor.org/discover/10.2307/1968551?uid=3737536&uid=2&uid=4&sid=21102434910441) is the really famous one. I don't know what came before that, if anything.

Comment: @MichaelBrown that should be an answer

Comment: @DavidZaslavsky I was waiting to see if anyone knew more of the history. I'll put it up now.

Comment: It's actually the Poincare group, the representations of the Lorentz group are found in a lot of papers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't really know the history of the subject, but the paper that has all the main results (the Wigner classification) is

[On Unitary Representations of the Inhomogeneous Lorentz Group,
E. Wigner,
Annals of Mathematics,
Second Series, Vol. 40, No. 1 (Jan., 1939), pp. 149-204](http://www.jstor.org/stable/1968551).